# Xpath from the current node using firefox webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

So i'm facing a small perforemence issue while using `findElement(By.xpath("..."))`

First i'm locating a `ul` element that contains around 20 `li` child.
by using then on each of the child i'm locating the inner `xpath` to the information by using the following:

```
List<WebElement> addrBookNames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='displayAddressUL']"));
for(WebElement addr : addrBookNames)
{
    String fullName = addr.findElement(By.xpath("li[@class='AddressFullName']/b")).getText();
    String addressLine = addr.findElement(By.xpath("li[@class='AddressAddressLine']")).getText();
    String city = addr.findElement(By.xpath("li[@class='AddressCity']")).getText();
    String county = addr.findElement(By.xpath("li[@class='country']")).getText();
    String phoneNumber = addr.findElement(By.xpath("li[@class='phone']")).getText();

}
```

The above code takes around 5 sec, checked it by using :

```
double stime = System.currentTimeMillis();
double TotalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - stime;
```

before and after.

Is there anything wrong with the way i'm extracting the inner `xpaths` from the selected node?

Comment: I think you are doing correct.

Comment: Should it take that long?

Comment: Time is depends on route that how many elements it need to route to find specific. so your mentioed time looks reasonable.

Comment: The webdriver dose not have any hash data structure for each element ? which then it should be O(1) per search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I would try  as alternative CSS selector approach and create 5 WebElement Lists ( already in split representation for searched fields):

```
List<WebElement> fullNames = driver.findELements(By.cssSelector("ul.displayAddressUL li.AddressFullName>b"));
List<WebElement> addressLines= driver.findELements(By.cssSelector("ul.displayAddressUL li.AddressAddressLine"));
List<WebElement> cities= driver.findELements(By.cssSelector("ul.displayAddressUL li.AddressCity"));
List<WebElement> countries=driver.findELements(By.cssSelector("ul.displayAddressUL li.country"));
List<WebElement> phoneNums=driver.findELements(By.cssSelector("ul.displayAddressUL li.phone"));

for (int i=0;i<fullNames.size(); i++){
String fullName= fullNames.get(i).getText();
String addressLine =addressLines.get(i).getText();
String city = cities.get(i).getText();
String county = countries.get(i).getText();
String phoneNumber = phoneNums.get(i).getText();
}
```

Also I'd like to add: 
CSS selectors perform far better than Xpath and it is well documented in Selenium community. Here are some reasons,

- Xpath engines are different in each browser, hence make them
  inconsistent
- IE does not have a native xpath engine, therefore selenium injects
  its own xpath engine for compatibility of its API. Hence we lose the
  advantage of using native browser features that WebDriver inherently
  promotes.
- Xpath tend to become complex and hence make hard to read in my
  opinion However there are some situations where, you need to use
  xpath, for example, searching for a parent element or searching
  element by its text (I wouldn't recommend the later).

More details on performance comparison you can get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t)

2) another alternative approach that I would recommend as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710549/selenium-relative-locator-searches-from-a-webelement-extremely-slow)
try to use `HtmlUnitDriver`, that will definitely increase your performance; 
OR: 
to use pure js wrapped by Javascipt executor  for text extraction like:

```
 String elem_css_selector="blablabla...";
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+elem_css_selector+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


       String resultingText= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
       Assert.assertTrue(resultingText.trim().equals("Expected Text")   );
```